# Add data row to datatable at predefined index

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

I have a datatable with one column:

```
this.callsTable.Columns.Add("Call", typeof(String));
```

I then want to add a row to that datatable, but want to give a specific index, the commented number is the desired index:

```
this.callsTable.Rows.Add("Legs"); //11
```

Update:

- Must be able to handle inputting hundreds of rows with unique
  indexes.
- The index must be what is defined by me no matter if there are enough
  rows in the table or not for the insertat function.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `DataTable.Rows.InsertAt` method.

```
DataRow dr = callsTable.NewRow(); //Create New Row
dr["Call"] = "Legs";              // Set Column Value
callsTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 11); // InsertAt specified position
```

See: [DataRowCollection.InsertAt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If the value specified for the pos parameter is greater than the
>   number of rows in the collection, the new row is added to the end.

Comment: What If i want to define certain indexes for several hundred rows? I dont want to have to do all that for each row as well as define a different Datarow variable each time which would also have to have a new name everytime. Also, I want the index to be what I choose no matter if there are enough rows in the table or not.

Comment: @RyanMurphy, `InsertAt` only accepts a `DataRow` as parameter, so you have to use that. but you can reuse the variable `dr` in your iteration.

Comment: Say I have: DataRow dr = callsTable.NewRow(); 
dr["Call"] = "Legs";              
callsTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 11); dr["Call"] = "Arms"; callsTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 9); It says this row is already in the datatable.

Comment: @RyanMurphy, you need to do `dr = dt.NewRow();` before using the `dr` again.

Comment: @Habib because of some conditions sometimes I only return fields (columns) without data so for that DT.NewRow() throws an exception of object reference.