# Change row position in DataTable or move row in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, dataset

I have a DataTable that must be sorted, however i want to return a particular row as the last row even after sorting the DataTable. I will identify this row by a string value in a partiucular column.

```
  public DataTable StandardReport3B(string missionId, string reportType, string startDate, string endDate)
    {
        List<long> missionIdList = new List<long>();
        string[] missionIds = missionId.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string mission in missionIds)
        {
            missionIdList.Add(Convert.ToInt64(mission));
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        object reportData = null;

        using (var ctx = new MedicalServiceEntities())
        {
            reportData = ctx.GetData(startDate, endDate, missionId).ToList();
        }

        dt = this.GenericListToDataTable(reportData);

        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName + " Asc";
        return dv.ToTable();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LINQ-to-DataSet`:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>(0) == "Special Value")
    .ThenBy(r => r.Field<string>(0))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

That works because the comparison returns either `true` or `false` and `false` is "lower".

---

In case someone just wants to know how to move the row in the table to another index as the title suggests: [Add data row to datatable at predefined index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636398/add-data-row-to-datatable-at-predefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

> I will identify this row by a string value in a partiucular column.

What about:

```
dv.Sort = "ParticularColumn ASC, " + dt.Columns[0].ColumnName + " ASC">
```

Where "ParticularColumn" is a column with an identical, low value for all rows except the one you want to be last - and this row has a higher value.